# Sending notifications in messaging apps_Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, notifications

I used firebase to create a messaging channel between two users that are chatting with each other. Assuming that you send someone a message and their phone is locked, the app should be able to send notifications (such as whats seen below) but instead it would say something like, "Bobby just you a new message". What's the name of that kind of notification and how is it normally used with messaging apps?

[image]

Comment: those are push notifications. But you have to write also the code for the server side to handle them.

Comment: Do you know of any sample projects on github that integrate the code for messaging push notification ?

Comment: I use PHP to do this. What language do you want to use?